# useRouter()'s .replace method failing when useRoute()'s .query object is assigned

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, pinia, vue-router4

I have this nested watcher:

```
const router = useRouter()
const route = useRoute()

const unwatch = watch(
  () => route.query, // required because useRoute() is async
  () => {
    // map url to routeStore on initial page load
    routeStore.query = route.query as any

    // map routeStore.query to url
    watch(
      () => routeStore.query,
      () => {
        router.replace({
          query: { search: 'test' }, // dummy, usually routeStore.query.search would be here
        })
      },
      { deep: true }
    )

    unwatch()
  },
  { deep: true }
)
```

its purpose is to:

1. map `routeStore.query` to the `url query`
2. at page load, copy the `url query` to the `routeStore`

the `routeStore` is created here:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { RouteStore } from '@/declarations'

export const useRouteStore = defineStore('route', {
  state: (): RouteStore => {
    return {
      query: {},
    }
  },
}
```

the routeStore is linked to an input text element and can be updated like so:

```
routeStore.query.search = 'helloWorld'
```

Problem is that as long as `routeStore.query = route.query as any` is commented in, `router.replace()` stops working. Any idea how I could debug this? When I remove the aforementioned line, it starts updating the `url` correctly.